# Самый быстрый способ пробежаться по массиву JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы, оптимизация, производительность, arraylist

Какой способ пробегаться по массиву является самым быстрым?
Я читал книгу про оптимизацию в Javascript, там было сказано, что самый быстрый способ так:

```
while(i--) { }
```

Я сравнил два способа: этот и обычный цикл:

```
for (var i = 1e7; i > 0; i = i - 1) {}
```

Вышло так, что обычный цикл работает гораздо быстрее, почему?
На форумах тоже писали, что способ с while'ом самый быстрый.

скорость работы проверял так:

```
var i = 1e7;
var t = performance.now();
while(i--) {}
console.log(performance.now() - t);

var t = performance.now();
for (var i = 1e7; i > 0; i = i - 1) {}
console.log(performance.now() - t);
```

Comment: на пустых циклах проверял? :) в каких браузерах?

Comment: Не знаю у меня выдаёт то первый быстрее то второй. И тело цикла лучше заполнить чем-нибудь.

Comment: мне кажется что нормальный оптимизатор должен выкинуть оба цикла. Если с `for` это вообще очевидно, то с `while` надо смотреть, вдруг `i` используется где-то во вне... Может в этом дело?

Comment: @Grundy , Здесь я не писал никаких вычислений. А так, я проверял эти способы на массивах, второй способ всё равно оказывался быстрее. Проверял в Chrome :)

Comment: @Рифат, стоит проверит остальные браузеры: FF,Safari, IE, EDGE. В любом из них результаты могут быть свои, кроме того, если идет речь об обработке массива, в тест стоит добавить случаи использования методов из Array: `forEach` например

Comment: @Grundy , спасибо за ответ :) Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый это for , есть много обзоров и статей на эту тему, например [тут](https://www.symphonious.net/2010/10/09/javascript-performance-for-vs-foreach/) , и был очень хороший бенчмарк на сайте [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/) , но на сейчас он неработает, может на момент прочтения ответа уже будет доступен, хорош этот бенчмарк был тем что там сравнивали не просто for vs foreach , а так же разные способы реализации for. В книге может быть описан теоретический момент, все современные браузеры оптимизируют код, и для них поведение for  наиболее предсказуемо , а значит его они ускоряют намного эффективнее.

Comment: на самом деле тема интересная , хоть сайт и не доступен но можно в гугле найти скриншоты, например такие http://image.slidesharecdn.com/functionalprogrammingusingunderscorejs-130420105505-phpapp01/95/functional-programming-using-underscorejs-78-638.jpg?cb=1366455340 , занимателен например такой момент что обратный for быстрее прямого, например я когда у себя в хроме тестировал то обратный оказался чуть быстрее прямого, не сильно но всёравно интересный факт